Inconsistent Function Evaluation with FunctionExpand
I'm pretty new to Mathematica and I came across the following apparent inconsistency which I am not able to explain.
I'm using Mathematica 14.1.0 to evaluate the Jacobi polynomial
$$P_{(n-1)}^{(-n,n-j)}(0)\quad\quad n,j\in\mathbb{N}$$
When I try to FunctionExpand this I get
FunctionExpand[JacobiP[n - 1, -n, n - j, 0], Assumptions -> Element[n | j, PositiveIntegers]]
(*(-1)^(-1 + n) 2^(-j + n)*)

Now if I try to evaluate these expressions for different $n,j$ I obtain inconsistent values. For instance for $n=10,j=3$

JacobiP[9,-10,7,0] = $-\frac{50643}{512}$
(-1)^9 2^7 = -128

Would be great if someone could provide me with an insight. Thank you!

I wonder if JacobiP[n,a,b,x] for negative a or b is well defined...

vs 13 yields Complex infinity. With all special functions, work is in progress. The formula body of Orthogonal Polynomials is very restricted.

Can be expressed by 2F1 :JacobiP[n - 1, -n, n - j,    0] == -(((-1)^n 2^(1 - n)     Gamma[-j + 2 n] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 1 - j + n, -1])/(   Gamma[n] Gamma[1 - j + n]))

Yeah @mariuszIwaniuk that's actually how I came to my jacobiP polynomial espression
